# Azure devops pipeline task "Synapse workspace deployment" failing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-synapse-analytics

Im tyring to run Synapse workspace deployment@2 task from azure pipeline as shown below

```
          - task: Synapse workspace deployment@2
            continueOnError: false
            inputs:
              TargetWorkspaceName: 'dev'
              ArtifactsFolder: $(ARTIFACTS_FOLDER)
              operation: 'validate'
```

also tried 'validateDeploy' operation

```
          - task: Synapse workspace deployment@2
            continueOnError: false
            inputs:
              operation: 'validateDeploy'
              ArtifactsFolder: '$(ARTIFACTS_FOLDER)'
              azureSubscription: '$(AZURE_RESOURCE_MANAGER_CONNECTION_NAME)'
              ResourceGroupName: '$(TARGET_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME_DEV)'
              TargetWorkspaceName: '$(TARGET_WORKSPACE_NAME_DEV)'
              DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: false
              DeployManagedPrivateEndpoints: false
              FailOnMissingOverrides: false
              Environment: 'prod'
              npmpackage: 'prod'
```

but getting error as below

> Stdout:   WARNING === BaseFileResourceProviderService: _processResource - Failed to load resource, loadingError: NameMismatch, Error: NameMismatch.
>
> Stdout:   ModelService: fetchAllInBackground - start
>
> Stdout:   ModelService: synchronize - finished
>
> Stdout:   ModelService: _backgroundFetch - finished, duration: 5.226471000001766, total nameds: 0
>
> Stdout:   ModelService: _backgroundFetch - finished, total unknown model types
>
> Stdout:   CmdApiApp: Publishable resource count: 0
>
> Stdout:   ERROR === CmdApiApp: Failed to export Synapse template. Error: {"stack":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parameters')\n    at PublisherUtils.createGlobalParametersForArmTemplate (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:180026:54)\n    at Function. (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:250303:136)\n    at step (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:441160:17)\n    at Object.next (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:441091:14)\n    at fulfilled (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:441046:24)","message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parameters')"}
>
> Shell execution failed.
> An error occurred during execution: Shell execution failed.
> ##[error]Encountered with exception:Shell execution failed.
> Finishing: Synapseworkspacedeployment

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAGiv.png)

Tried changing all the values for input but same error still persists.

Comment: I assume the issue is with the contents of the Parameter $(ARTIFACTS_FOLDER).  Have you tried, in the validate only deployment, replacing the parameter with the hard-coded value and seeing if it will validate then?  
e.g.  ArtifactsFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ArtifactFolder'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery#configure-the-deployment-task

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same issue.